# How to enable remote debugging in JBOSS 5?

Tags: debugging, jboss, remote-debugging

How do you enable remote debugging in JBoss 5? The usual line from JBoss 4:

```
set JAVA_OPTS= -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
```

As can be found in other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse) do not seem to work. The server never suspends. Googling "jboss 5 remote debug" doesn't bring up anything in the JBoss docs. Did something change from JBoss 4? How can I remotely debug my JBoss 5 server from eclipse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have `suspend=n` in your options. Change this to `suspend=y`.

Or is the line you posted not the one you're using with JBoss?

Comment: Doh! You care completely right. I had switched it off a few months ago and forgotten! Too much time w/ stack traces this week.

Answer (score 6):

We have to do 2 changes to debug remote java application that is running in JBoss

1. Configure in JBoss
2. Creating remote debugger in in eclipse

   1. Open run.conf.bat(windows) or run.conf(Linux) file in JBoss bin folder.

go to the below lines

```
`# Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging`
 #JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

and remove hash in JAVA_OPTS

```
# Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y
```

Restart the server if it is started.
2. In Eclipse, Run -> Debug configuration -> Remote Java Application and create a new.
Note that you have to give port that is mentioned in run.conf.bat file