# How to setup remote debugging of an eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging, rcp

My RCP app is not working properly outside of the development environment so I'm trying to setup a remote debugging session.

I start the app using the following parameters:

```
-vmargs -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

I then created a new debug profile which connects to port 8000. In the debug perspective I can see that the connection was successful and the various threads are listed. I should say that the app has a number of bundles (model, UI, services etc.) so I chose the bundle containing the `.product` as the project to debug.

But, although there seems to be a connection, I cannot set breakpoints. At least, I can set a breakpoint but it never halts.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534384/how-to-enable-remote-debugging-in-jboss-5/24325132#24325132

Answer (score 0):

-vmargs -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y

Please use above VM arguments. suspend should be y.