# problem migrating jboss from 4.2 to 5.1 (GWT rendenring issue)

Tags: jsf, gwt, jboss, richfaces, upgrade

I'm having an error trying to run my application in jboss5.1 after a migration. I've resolved a lot of issues now, but my app still doesn't work :(

I'm working with GWT and JSF. Jboss has a clean boot, even my login page loads ok, but when it arrives to the GWT menu it doesn't show anything, and the log doesn't show any error.

I don't have a clue of what can it be. Maybe a library a have to update for jboss5.1 or something like that.

Please if you have any idea let me know. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no any messages in your log, you need to debug. Try [remote debugger](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/eclipse-jboss-remote-debug.html) in Eclipse.

See also:

- ["Configuring Eclipse for Remote Debugging"](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/eclipse-jboss-remote-debug.html)
- ["Debugging remote tests"](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/latest/en-US/html/debugging.html)
- ["JBoss debugging in Eclipse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse)