# JBoss 4.2 - multiple applications in debug mode on same JBoss?

Tags: java, debugging, jakarta-ee, jboss

How can I run several applications (with all of them) in debug mode on the same `JBoss 4.2` server? Is this available in `JBoss 4.2`? If not then in which `JBoss` version is it available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug mode is all about JVM and has nothing specific to JBoss at all.

Single JVM can have only one debugger client attached at the same moment.

I guess you wanted to do debugging is several IDE windows with different open projects.

Some options available:

- create a workspace with all projects needed in same place
- temporally attach/detach only in project of most current interest, then switch to another one

See also

[JBoss debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse)

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 4.2 Please go through

https://community.jboss.org/message/571476?_sscc=t

Comment: There is a lot of information in the thread and the topic discussed is not about the question I have asked. I guess you know where it talks about my problem, so could you please point out where does it talk about running several applications on the SAME JBoss instance with more than one application running in debug mode - because I could not find it?