# How to setup JBoss-EAP with Eclipse and carry out debugging; using "minimal" server configuration

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jboss5.x

How to setup Eclipse to use JBoss-EAP for debugging and also minimal profile.

Can someone please give us details on how to do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at this article;

http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/jboss-eclipse.html

- The "server configuration" that you wish to run i.e. default, minimal etc; it can be specified and the tutorial does specify that. Read again, carefully.
- Debugging: once you have configured the server in your eclipse; specify the breakpoints and then right click your project and choose Debug As -> Debug on Server.

If you need remote debugging; [JBoss debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse)

Comment: but this does not show how to get the minimal working in eclipse or debugging with breakpoints