# How do I debug a war file on a remote machine?

Tags: java, debugging, jboss, remote-debugging

If I have a jboss server running on another machine and I scp my war file to that machine, how do I debug the war? what commands would I use? How do I do this in my terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run jboss with the debug arguments on the remote machine:

```
 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=54371,server=y,suspend=y
```

`address` - this will be the port you want to connect on

`server` - signifies it will be the server

`suspend` - will block execution of the application until a debugger connects (specify `n` if you want the application to begin before a debugger connects to it)

If using Eclipse, Debug as a `Remote Java Application`. You simply provide the project to debug, the IP of the remote machine and the port you specified.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the firewall allows an incoming connection on the port where the debugger is listening.

Comment: For an app server, like JBoss, i would usually set `suspend=n`. That lets the server start up normally, after which you connect, set a breakpoint somewhere in your request-handling code, and fire a request at it. Of course, if you need to debug the startup process, then you need `suspend=y`, but that's less common, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have an IDE to do the debugging from - which in most case people use Eclipse.

1. Need to set up your JBoss to allow debug connection
2. Connect to your JBoss, on its debugging port, through Eclipse.

Check out this post [JBoss debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse)