# JBoss remote debugging issue

Tags: jboss, remote-debugging

I added the following line to the run.sh file which activates remote debugging:

set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y %JAVA_OPTS%

However, it causes the server to not be restarted! I don't even get an exception, because the server.log file isn't updated at all!

Comment: Try using `suspend=n`.
See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568756/how-do-i-debug-a-war-file-on-a-remote-machine?lq=1.

Comment: But http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534384/how-to-enable-remote-debugging-in-jboss-5 suggests the opposite...

Comment: @Vadzim is right `suspend=y` makes the VM wait until you connect a debugger `suspend=n` starts normally.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Windows syntax in shell script for *nix OS.  You need to add something like this to run.sh:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
export JAVA_OPTS
```