# Debug application in Jboss 5.1 using local debugging mode in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, ejb, jboss5.x

I am trying to setup my eclipse project to be able to debug an EJB application that is deployable in Jboss 5.1. To configure the debugging options i used the options described here:

[JBoss debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse)

I tried the above and it works but with the following limitations:

- If i change any code, i have to rebuild the application and re-deploy into Jboss and restart the server. We use ANT to build the project so having to rebuild and re-deploy the application because of a small change is not really ideal.
- I managed two approaches:

The first one as described in [JBoss debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse). This requires that i copy the war file manually, start up jboss remotely then start the remote debugger in ecliplse.

The second approach is i would still copy the war file manually to jboss but not start jboss remotely. Instead i would start jboss within eclipse. This sort of works but the problem is i still have to do the manual deployment when i make a change.

I have debugged an application within eclipse running in Tomcat before and with that all i had to do is just restart the server if i make a change to the code.

Is it possible to debug an EJB application locally within Eclipse so that if i make a code change all i need to do is restart the server locally and not need to redeploy the war file?