# Debugging an EAR application?

Tags: eclipse, ant, jboss5.x, ear

I'm quite new to an EAR application. I'm trying to fix some issues in the code. I'm using ANT to build the application along with JBoss 5.1.0.GA. How can I do things like Run On Server, Debug On Server in eclipse?

When I right click on the Run on Server/Debug on Server. I get a server error pop-up saying: The selection did not contain any resources that can run on a sever.

How can I get it to work within eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should debug your application remotely. See this question on how you set up a remote debugger with Eclipse and JBoss:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/516214/89435

Comment: Just a dumb question. I should do remote debugging for a locally installed JBoss Server?

Comment: Yes, even if it sounds weird, remote debugging works for locally installed servers also :-)

Comment: Nice, I'm having trouble selecting the project. My project selection window is empty.

Comment: Have you created the project inside the eclipse workspace? If you did, then this is weird...

Comment: I basically drag and dropped an existing workspace from another machine to my eclipse workspace and imported it to my IDE.

Comment: keep the project selection blank. this works very well if you have more then 1 project that has code for the artifacts deployed