# Remote debug JBoss AS 7.1 from Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x, remote-debugging

I read some guides on the subject and made the following steps.

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/eclipse-jboss-remote-debug.html?page=8
https://community.jboss.org/thread/177687
[JBoss debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse)

The guides have some distinctions but on the whole they are similar.

**The steps I made.**

1. I compiled and deployed my web project and deployed it on JBoss AS
   7.1 by clicking ***Run on Server -> JBoss AS 7.1*** in Eclipse.
2. I stopped JBoss AS in Eclipse.
3. I uncommented the line

   `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"`

in the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf` file

4. I executed `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh`
5. I updated the page localhost:8080/MyProject/ in the browser and it
   worked
6. I executed ***Debug -> Debug Configurations*** in Eclipse, then I created
   a new configuration with the localhost as the host, 8787 as the
   port, and MyProject as the project name.
7. I pressed the Debug button in Eclipse.

When I reach a breakpoint I added, nothing happens.

I expected that Eclipse would stop at the breakpoint as it does in a simple Java application project. What did I do wrong?

Eclipse version: Indigo.

Java.

```
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
```

**Edit #1.**

1. ***Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's***
2. Edit JRE being used
3. Edit 'Default VM Arguments' line

   -XX:+UseParallelGC

It didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making the changes in **"standalone.conf"**, make the change in "**standalone.conf.bat"** .

Remove the **rem** from the line "rem set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"" .

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start JBoss with a few extra options to the JVM. You can set these either in **`standalone.xml`**, or via the **`JAVA_OPTS`** environment variable. The options look basically the same, but for this post I will use `JAVA_OPTS`. Read this post from the JBoss Community forum if you want to use `standalone.xml` to configure the JVM parameters.

Add this line to your existing `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

The port number (`8787`) above must match your Eclipse setup (see below).

Finally, you will need to tell Eclipse how to connect to the remote process. In Eclipse, click the **Debug** button’s drop-down arrow and select “**Debug Configurations**”.

- In that dialog, navigate to “**Remote Java Application**” and click the “**New**” button.
- Under “**Project**” select the project that contains the code you want to debug.
- Under Connection Type make sure “**Standard (Socket Attach)**” is selected.
- Under Connection Properties, make sure the host (e.g., `localhost`) and port (which must match the port spec in the `JAVA_OPTS`, in this case `8787`) are set.
- Click on the “**Source**” tab and add any projects containing code you want to debug (if there are other projects in your workspace that contain code other than the main project).
- In the Common tab, under “**Display in favorites menu**” select the Debug icon and a handy dandy icon will appear in your Debug toolbar dropdown (the name will be the same as the Project setting from earlier).

If JBoss is already running (with the options set earlier) click Debug to attach. If not, start JBoss, then click **Debug** to attach.

Now you can set breakpoints, step through your code, etc.

Have fun!