# How to debug a JBoss 7.1 application in eclipse Luna

Tags: java, debugging, jboss7.x, eclipse-luna

Anybody knows how can I enable the debug port of JBoss if I start the JBoss inside of eclipse? I have followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295569/1465758 but the debug port (8787) is only open if I start JBoss from a command line outside of eclipse Luna. If I open eclipse Luna and try to start the JBoss server the debug port 8787 will be still closed! Seems that eclipse Luna is not using the changed standalone.conf  file.

On eclipse I have installed the JBossAS Tools V3.0.0.Beta3-v20140718-1832-B70 plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now install the "JBoss Developer Studio (Core Features)" plugin (V8.0.0.Beta3). Now I can debug JBoss applications via the debug icon of the JBoss panel.

[image]

I'm sure this didn't work yesterday (with the "JBossAS Tools V3.0.0.Beta3" plugin).

Also notice that I must removing and reinstalling the eclipse IDE befor I could installing the JBoss Developer Studio plugin. Otherwise (without reinstalling eclipse) I cannot install the JBoss Developer Studio plugin. I assume there is any old stuff of the removed JBoss Tools 3.0.0 plugin which prevents a successful installation of the new plugin ...

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to debug like in the answer, but its not working in JBoss 7.1. I found that it is bug of JBoss 7.1.x. Look here: https://developer.jboss.org/message/723813

I downloaded EAP 6.1 (old name - JBoss 7.2) - its working perfect with JBoss Tools (Luna) 4.2.3 Final.