# Eclipse Remote debugging with jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss, remote-debugging

How can I configure remote debugging in Eclipse with JBOSS server 4.x version?

So far,

**Step1**: I have modified the run.confg file. By uncommenting the below line. Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

**Step2** : Then I configured Eclipse in debug configurations. It's saying:

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
```

Comment: When someone answers your question, you must bother to say whether it worked for you or not.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse

Comment: @Ravi did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 17):

What you are asking is not specific to either Java EE or JBoss 4.x - you can debug any Java process in case you specified the remote debugging runtime parameters when starting the JVM.

In your setting the `-Xdebug` parameter is missing, so your line would be:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Now it should be able to connect, in case you are using the correct host and your specified port 8787. In case it's still not working, it's most likely a firewall issue blocking the port.

Comment: I just had a similar problem and came across this answer. It is good. It is worth noting, however that the -Xdebug parameter is not needed for JDK versions later than 1.4.x. Something like this should work in newer JDKs: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787`