# Can We Debug the java file which is deploy in jboss application server?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, web-deployment, jboss6.x

Will my web application project deploy in jboss application server?

if it is deployed in jboss server of eclipse, how to debug it ?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182666/eclipse-remote-debugging-with-jboss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a remote debugger if you're using Eclipse. All you need is a server name, port, and to add some configurations to the JBoss launch.

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787, server=y, suspend=n
```

These arguments should be used to run JBoss, then you can connect to port 8787 (or whatever you specify) to remotely debug.

Comment: Ur answer got me a idea.for more reference check out this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAVpep3zLdg

Comment: @YellowFlash Glad to hear it :)