# How to set up HotSwap in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hotswap

I am new to Eclipse thus this may be really beginner questions from me.
I want to set up hot-swap in Eclipse so non structural changes can be done and seen right in the running application. (Game development)

I think I have to have tomcat running. I don`t know how it works, never tried it but I have it in my Eclipse Servers tab configured, I can run it but it will generate bunch of errors when I debug with tomcat:

> INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.

Please, could you navigate me in depth step by step how to set up the code replace in Eclipse? Also there are some External Web modules etc. Do I need it with Tomcat for hotswap?

Comment: That's not an error, it's an info message

Answer (score 2):

You need **[DCEVM](https://dcevm.github.io/)** + **[HotswapAgent](http://www.hotswapagent.org/quick-start)**.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28790466/248847) to one of the [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861543/is-it-possible-to-do-hotswapping-of-atg-classes).